# Using resource files (.resx) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor, resx

I'm trying to use localization in my project but I can't find a way to access my resx files from javascript. I have been looking around a bit and I don't think the 'AJAX call' method would be ideal for my project since I have quiet a lot of string that need to be fetched and it would just have to spam the server hard!

if I just put it in my HTML then it works with this code:

```
@using Resources
<p>@Html.Raw(ISt_Localization.January)</p>
```

I guess one of the things I could do is put all the strings in a hidden div and then get the content from the divs in my javascript but this wouldn't be very effective..

Comment: is your js code in external .js files?

Comment: The resx files reside on the server, JavaScript resides on the client. You need to provide a communication method, wether thats a hidden field or ajax is up to you, but javascript can't read resx files.

Comment: @dakait: yes, does that matter? if there is a workaround that requires my code to be internal then I could do that?
liam hmmm okey. I'm kinda new to using resource files so thanks for explaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar situation and in my case, I created a separate partial view which only contained a javascript block where I put all the resource strings required for use in client side logic. Every resource string was defined as a javascript variable. You could also create an associative array.

In your partial view:

```
var Resources = {
        January : "@Html.Raw(ISt_Localization.January)",
        February : "@Html.Raw(ISt_Localization.February)",
        ...
};
```

Comment: Works like a charm! created a partial view. and make a list like in your example. Then used the items where I needed them! wish I could double vote this up!

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the below thing directly

```
@using Resources

<script>
var value = '@Resource.January';
/* work with value 
.......
.....

*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a totally different approach.

I want to have the resource strings required by my Javascript files be part of my resx files.

Every key in my resource file which starts with *js* has to become available in Javascript.

In global.asax, in Application_OnStart I build Javascript files for all supported languages on the fly. 
Because this only happens at the start of the application, it does not matter if it takes a few seconds.

Advantages:

- All translations in one place (in the rex files which you use for your .NET application (C# or VB), but also for your Javascript code
- Always up to date
- Very fast, because we are going to use variables to get the translations

Building the Javascript file is easy. 
Iterate through all key value pairs in all resx-files. Just pick out the keys starting with `_js_`.
Save the key value pair in the Javascript file.

So if the key value pair in the resx-file (languageSupport_es.resx) is '_js_Hello', 'Hola', 
I write in my Javascript file (languageSupport_es.js) `var Hello = 'Hola';`

So `alert(Hello)` will give you 'Hola' if the current language is Spanish.

The only thing I now have to take care of, is using the right 'language Javascript file' is loaded before my other Javascript files.
So if the language is Spanish, I ONLY include my 'Spanish language Javascript file' (languageSupport_es.js) first.

Easy no? If somebody is interested, I can show some example code...